Cartesian tree index

input
The first line of the input file contains an integer number N -- the number of pairs you should build cartesian tree out of (1 ≤ N ≤ 50 000). The following N lines contain two numbers each -- given pairs (ki, ai). For each pair |ki|, |ai| ≤ 30 000. All main keys and all auxiliary keys are different, i.e. ki ≠ kj and ai ≠ aj for each i ≠ j.

output
On the first line of the output file print YES if it is possible to build a cartesian tree out of given pairs or NO if it is not. If the answer is positive, on the following N lines output the tree. Let nodes be numbered from 1 to N corresponding to pairs they contain as they are given in the input file. For each node output three numbers -- its parent, its left child and its right child. If the node has no parent or no corresponding child, output 0 instead.

example



input
7
5 4
2 2
3 9
0 5
1 3
6 6
4 11

output
YES
2 3 6
0 5 1
1 0 7
5 0 0
2 4 0
1 0 0
3 0 0



my current code

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node {
    int k, a;
    int index;
    struct Node* left, * right, * parent;
};

// function prototype
int compare(const void* a, const void* b);
void printNode(struct Node* nodes, int i);

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    struct Node* nodes = (struct Node*)malloc(n * sizeof(struct Node));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf_s("%d %d", &nodes[i].k, &nodes[i].a);

        nodes[i].index = i;
        nodes[i].left = nodes[i].right = nodes[i].parent = NULL;
    }
    qsort(nodes, n, sizeof(struct Node), compare); // sort nodes based on k for BST property

    int top = -1; // top is variable of stack
    struct Node** stack = (struct Node**)malloc(n * sizeof(struct Node*));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        struct Node* popped = NULL;
        while (top >= 0 && stack[top]->a > nodes[i].a) {
            popped = stack[top--];
        }
        if (top >= 0) {
            stack[top]->right = &nodes[i];
            nodes[i].parent = stack[top];
        }
        if (popped) {
            nodes[i].left = popped;
            popped->parent = &nodes[i];
        }
        stack[++top] = &nodes[i];
    }
    printf("YES\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printNode(nodes, i);
    }
    free(nodes);
    free(stack);
    return 0;
}

int compare(const void* a, const void* b) {
    // If negative, first value > second value
    // If 0, first value == second value
    // If positive, first value < second value
    return ((struct Node*)a)->k - ((struct Node*)b)->k;
}

void printNode(struct Node* nodes, int i) {
    if (nodes[i].parent) {
        printf("%d ", nodes[i].parent->index + 1);
    }
    else {
        printf("0 ");
    }

    if (nodes[i].left) {
        printf("%d ", nodes[i].left->index + 1);
    }
    else {
        printf("0 ");
    }

    if (nodes[i].right) {
        printf("%d\n", nodes[i].right->index + 1);
    }
    else {
        printf("0\n");
    }
}


my current result


input
7
5 4
2 2
3 9
0 5
1 3
6 6
4 11

output
YES
5 0 0
2 4 0
0 5 1
1 0 7
3 0 0
2 3 6
1 0 0



This seems like the perfect time to learn how to debug your programs. Like for example use a debugger to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values. I also recommend you use pen-and-paper to visualize the data, pointers and variables.

"Let nodes be numbered from 1 to N corresponding": Let's change nodes[i].index = i; to nodes[i].index = i + 1; and then the index + 1s to index in the printNode()?
